# Debugging WCF Web Service Faults

Tags: c#-4.0, wcf

I am trying to debug a web service exception.  I have both the client and the service running in debug mode in Visual Studio 2010, C#, .net 4.0 framework.

When I run the client, and get it to call the web service, I get an exception:

> **Type:** System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,  System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   **Error Message:** The type initializer for 'myService.Service' threw an exception.
>   **Source:** mscorlib

However, the service shows no exceptions whatsoever.

The stack trace that I got seems to indicate that the call was made, and the reply was being handled (even if the reply was an exception):

> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Can someone give pointers on what else I need to do to debug this?

I'm currently setting up the [Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) tool to see if that will tell me anything more.

Comment: The trace viewer would help you. There seems to be some configuration issue. It could be as simple as mis-spelled service name in the web.config.

Comment: What binding are you using? If it's an http supported binding, try to navigate to the URL it's being hosted at locally in your browser to see if that succeeds. Usually if it doesn't, it's a configuration setting problem.

Comment: @jskiles: That's part of the problem. It's browser-navigable quite happily, so *most* of the configuration is fine.

Comment: @amit_g  Still poking around with the trace viewer... but not sure what I'm doing, so going back to basics to see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message suggests that your service class `myService.Service` has a static constructor or field initializer expression with a bug in it, causing an unhandled exception to escape the static ctor when the Service type is loaded.

In the service host process under the debugger, just put breakpoints on the static ctor and field initializer expressions, and step until the underlying exception occurs.

The Fusion (.NET class loader) Log will likely get you there also, if you know how to use that.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been poking a bit with the fusion log viewer previously (on a different issue), but it's not showing me anything (at all) now.  Nice tip about the static constructor etc. I'll press on that a little and see what breaks. (+1 all round, pity I can't up it more :-)

Comment: That was it.  For some reason my debug setup is only working intermittently.  About one time in five time the service side will allow me to step through... and that showed precisely what you said: an error in the instantiation of a field. Much obliged!  Now to figure out the debug flakiness.

Answer (score 2):

Error is likely a missing dependency on server side. Launch fuslogvw.exe, enable failure logging, reproduce the problem and look for related failure records.

Comment: Another good tool: +1.  It's not showing me anything, though.